# How to list all AWS RDS instances and their tags in CSV

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I'm new to the AWS CLI and I am trying to build a CSV server inventory of my project's AWS RDS instances that includes their tags.

I have done so successfully with EC2 instances using this:

```
aws ec2 describe-isntances\
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress, InstanceType, [Tags[?Key=='Name'.Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key=='ENV'.Value] [0][0] ]'\
--output text | sed -E 's/\s+/,/g' >> ec2list.csv
```

The above command gives me a CSV with the Ip address, instance type, as well as the values of the listed tags.

However, I am currently trying to do so unsuccessfully on RDS instances with this:

```
aws rds describe-db-isntances\
--query 'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, DBInstanceArn, [Tags[?Key=='Component'.Value] [0][0], [Tags[?Key=='Engine'.Value] [0][0] ]'
--output text | sed -E 's/\s+/,/g' >> rdslist.csv
```

The RDS command only returns the instance arn and identifier but the tag values show up as none even though they definitely do have a value.

What modifications need to be made to my RDS query to show the tag values/is this even possible? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what it returns if you just run `aws rds describe-db-instances --output json`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need one more command https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference//API_ListTagsForResource.html.

You can wrap the 2 scripts in shell script like the below example.

```
#!/bin/bash
ARNS=$(aws rds describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[].DBInstanceArn" --output text)
for line in $ARNS; do
    TAGS=$(aws rds list-tags-for-resource --resource-name "$line" --query "TagList[]")
    echo $line $TAGS
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized that tags can be displayed in my original query. It does not use Tags like EC2 instances but TagList. E.g,

```
aws rds describe-db-isntances\
--query 'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, DBInstanceArn, [TagList[?Key=='Component'.Value] [0][0], [TagList[?Key=='Engine'.Value] [0][0] ]'
--output text | sed -E 's/\s+/,/g' >> rdslist.csv
```